# If ELAC 1 is under MEL why is it a NO GO item when carrying out EDTO on the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, mel

In the MEL for the A320 it is mentioned that ELAC 1 is a NO GO if carrying out EDTO operations. Why is ELAC 1 specifically for EDTO? In that case shouldn't it be for non EDTO operations also.

This somewhat contradicts ELAC 2 being a NO GO. Could someone please clarify this with an official reference.

Comment: For those of us not embroiled in A320 operations: ELAC - ELevator Aileron Computer, and EDTO - Extended Diversion Time Operations

Comment: EDTO is the new term for ETOPS, not A320 specific, but the name didn't catch on.

Comment: @ymb1 didn't mean to pertain specifically to the A320. But while conducting EDTO on the A320.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, operating ETOPS/EDTO takes into consideration worst-case scenario situations (EMER ELEC CONFIG) where you will only have ELAC1 working.

In addition, its mentioned that ELAC2 in MEL is a NO-GO item due to the logic behind the system operation where it will allow ELAC2 to work first always, and in case ELAC2 fails ELAC1 will take over.

According to :

- **A320 FCOM ATA (27-10-20) Architecture (Pitch control)**. In normal operations, ELAC2 controls the elevator and the horizontal stabilizer, if a failure occurs in ELAC2 the system shifts pitch control to ELAC1.
- **A320 QRH ABN-18 ELEC (ELEC EMER CONFIG SYS REMAINING)**, In the emergency electric configuration the ELAC2 wouldn't be available when the emergency generator is running and ELAC1 will be the only available.
- **A320 FCOM ABN PRO (ELEC EMER CONFIG)**, ELAC2 is written within the INOP SYS table to confirm what happens when the aircraft goes into the emergency electric configuration.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't still fully understand from your answer why it's a NO GO

Answer (score -2):

An item may be on the MEL be sure being into for a flight, day ,or other period is an acceptable risk but when giving that approval the authorities always consider the " next worst failure" which most often is the second version of the " failed "item. It was judged that the pilot workload, or reduction on safety margins , when under Erops ( I'm a traditionalist) and potentially up to  3 hours or more from a laudable airfield.

As a general eules, far fewer items are on an erops aircraft rather than an Aircraft released for "normal" service, which assumes a diversion airfield within one hour. (The last MMEL I negotiated was parts of the Airbus A400M avionics, 8 ish years ago)

Comment: David, I realize that perhaps English isn't your first language, but please get some help editing your basic grammar.  That first sentence especially makes no sense at all.